# Oracle pl block to be execute in program

Tags: c#, oracle

I am new to C#. I want to know how to execute an Oracle pl sql statement block in C#.

I am writing a pl sql query in string builder and want to fetch return value of the same.

```
StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(" declare ");
sp.Append(" v_acid   varchar(10);");
sp.Append(" v_Cid    varchar(10);");
sp.Append(" begin ");
sp.Append(" select acid,cust into v_acid,v_Cid from account where       account='112111' ");
sp.Append(" end ");
```

I am expecting the return value of `v_acid` and `v_Cid` to be set in string variables. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, you have to download the `OracleClientProvider` and add it to the references of your project. This will give you the ability to communicate with an `Oracle` database using `c#`.

Then the general configuration of that you want would be something like this:

```
using(var connection new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = " SELECT acid, cust "+
                      " FROM account "+
                      " WHERE account='112111' ";

    connection.Open();
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read(); 

    OracleNumber acid = reader.GetOracleNumber(0);
    OracleNumber cust = reader.GetOracleNumber(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actualy i have mentioned a small piece of code.The actual query is seems like a procedure in which i will fetch the values from difference tables add it in declared variable, then doing some calculation on the variable and generate a report. Hence i want to know how to execute pl sql block.